# Best method to parse out and store sections of string with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, string, parsing

I have converted some XML into an object, and used JSON.stringify to convert that into a string. The output looks something like this:

```
['{"plist"',
'{"$"',
'{"version"',
'"1.0"},"dict"',
'[{"key"',
'["telemetryParserTest"],"dict"',
'[{"key"',
'["compilerRevision","minimumVersion","name","peel","peelParams","revision","scenes"],"string"',
'["BBP',
'1.62.10","11","telemetryParserTest","yes","orient=portrait,scale=70,type=fit,dy=0,dx=0","13-04-2015 05',
'22',
'02"],"array"',
'[{"dict"',
'[{"key"',
'["animation_store","classes","functions","models","name","variables"],"array"',
'[{"dict"',
'[{"key"',
'["name","speed","start","stop","type"],"string"',
'["FadeInFast","0.002","0","1","fade"]},{"key"',
'["name","speed","start","stop","type"],"string"',
'["FadeIn","0.001","0","1","fade"]},{"key"',
'["name","speed","start","stop","type"],"string"',
'["FadeOut","0.001","1","0","fade"]}]},{"dict"',
'[{"key"',
'["alpha","clickable","location","name","orientation","scale","scaleFactor","transformMode","type"],"string"',
'["0","no","0,0,0","Mesh_3D","0,0,1,0","1","1,1,1","enhanced","phantom"]},{"key"',
'["base","clickable","name"],"string"',
'["Mesh_3D","yes","Sensor"]},{"key"',
'["alpha","attachment","clickable","model","name","orientation","scale","transformMode","type"],"string"',
'["0","screen","no","system.plane","SS","0,0,1,0","1","enhanced","phantom"]},{"key"',
'["base","hidden","name"],"string"',
'["SS","yes","SS_hide"]},{"key"',
'["base","clickable","hidden","name"],"string"',
'["SS","yes","yes","SS_hs"]},{"key"',
'["base","clickable","name"],"string"',
'["SS","yes","SS_sensor"]}]},{"dict"',
'[{"key"',
'["commands","name"],"array"',
'[{"dict"',
'[{"key"',
'["arg1","arg2","arg3","function"],"string"',
'["\'54555\'","\'test blipp has started\'","\'user={{user}}\'","telemetry"]}]}],"string"',
'["onShow"]},{"key"',
'["commands","name"],"array"',
'[{"dict"',
'[{"key"',
'["arg1","arg2","arg3","function"],"string"',
'["\'54555\'","\'Fake button was clicked\'","\'user={{user}}\'","telemetry"]}]}],"string"',
'["FakeButton.onClick"]}]},{"dict"',
'[{"key"',
'["base","location","name","scaleFactor","texture"],"string"',
'["SS","0,0,0","FakeButton","1,1,1","trans.png"]}]},{"string"',
'["sW=system.screenWidth*1.003","sH=system.screenHeight*1.004","user=\\"Patrick\\"","mW=marker.width","mH=marker.height"]}],"string"',
'["default"]}]}]}]}]}}' ]
```

There are two instances of the word "telemetry" in this string, so 2nd place solution would be to count those out and return the number. Best case would be to navigate backwards from the word "telemetry" and return the array that it lives in as well as the three preceding "arguments" that are in it's local section.

Anyone have any ideas on the best methods?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like it would be **much** easier to work with the object than it would be to work with the stringified object.

Comment: Thanks, could you point me in the right direction to operate on the object to achieve the above desired result?

Comment: Is this just random data that can have any unpredictable structue or do you have more information about it?

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're looking for here.  I agree with Pointy, though.  It sounds much more likely to be useful to deal with the original pre-stringified object.